# received unexpected handshake message of type *tls.serverKeyExchangeMsg when waiting for *tls.certificateStatusMsg

Tags: ssl, go, https, tls1.2

I need to check some website for updates, my script is working for all the sites I tried except one.

I'm pretty sure it's something related to TLS/SSL but I didn't find any useful information about the error.

Here is the script:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "crypto/tls"
)

func main(){

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DisableKeepAlives:   false,
            MaxIdleConnsPerHost: 10,
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                InsecureSkipVerify: true,
            },
        },
    }

    fmt.Println(client)

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", os.Args[1], nil)

    _, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Something bad happened: ", err)
    }

}
```

And here is the output:

```
[root@74dfbb491710 wd]# go run ssl.go https://google.com
&{0xc4200ce000 <nil> <nil> 0s}
[root@74dfbb491710 wd]# go run ssl.go https://jobs-eu.hudson.com
&{0xc4200e4000 <nil> <nil> 0s}
Something bad happened:  Get https://jobs-eu.hudson.com: tls: received unexpected handshake message of type *tls.serverKeyExchangeMsg when waiting for *tls.certificateStatusMsg
```

Do I need to add some code to handle the handshake? Why the website is sending me that unexpected message?

Comment: This seems to be a known problem with go's TLS library talking to some servers. [A patch](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8549) was sent back in the days of go 1.4 to make the `certificateStatusMsg` optional, but it never got merged. The patch seems to implement RFC4366 more accurately, so I'm not sure why it was not integrated.

Comment: interesting, what go version are you using ?

Comment: @GujaratSantana I tried with 1.4 and 1.8, same behaviour.

Comment: There is no version that fixes this, the patch was never merged: [here](https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/handshake_client.go#L336) is the relevant section from the client handshake code. Go requires a `certificateStatusMsg` when the RFC says "The server MAY return a "certificate_status" message."

Comment: @greenkey: the patch linked above "should work", but I realize patching go is a bit annoying.

Comment: @Marc thanks, I'll try

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in Go's TLS handshake handling. There is a patch that was sent in around go 1.4: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8549.
However, it has not been applied as of 1.9.2.

The patch itself clearly shows that it's a mistake in Go's implementation:

```
// RFC4366 on Certificate Status Request:       
// The server MAY return a "certificate_status" message.
```

Whereas the go TLS client was basically implementing "The server MUST return ...".

We can reproduce the problem with a smaller example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    _, err := http.Get(os.Args[1])
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

And running:

```
$ go run foo.go https://jobs-eu.hudson.com
Get https://jobs-eu.hudson.com: tls: received unexpected handshake message of type *tls.serverKeyExchangeMsg when waiting for *tls.certificateStatusMsg
```

Applying the above patch to the [go 1.9.2](https://golang.org/dl/#stable) source and rebuilding now yields the correct functionality:

```
~/tmp$ GOROOT=${HOME}/tmp/go go/bin/go run foo.go https://jobs-eu.hudson.com
<nil>
```

To patch Go, I did the following: (but you may want to follow the [install from source](https://golang.org/doc/install/source) instructions, they're more thorough)

- download the [go 1.9.2 source tarball](https://golang.org/dl/#stable)
- extract it to `~/tmp/go`
- apply the patch: `~/tmp/go$ patch -p1 < /tmp/OptionalCertificateStatus.patch`
- rebuild: `~/tmp/go$ GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=<my previous go install> ./all.bash`
- run as mentioned above

I've pinged the [patch issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8549), I'm curious to know why this patch hasn't been picked.

**Update**: patch is [now merged](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/86115). 1.11 is probably the earliest release to have it (I'm guessing based on the fact that 1.10 is already in beta).

Comment: Where does OptionalCertificateStatus.patch come from? Also where does ./all.bash come from? It looks like go1.10rc1 has the fix so I'm trying to apply that to 1.9.3. I guess I'll just compile it and run it separate from 1.9.3

Comment: The patch comes from either the github issue linked at the beginning of my answer, or from the go-review link in the update. all.bash is part of the go source tarball.